# Access GPIO Pins of Pi(A) from Pi(B)

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors

#### My setup :

*DHT 11 Sensor on Pi(A)* and I want to access the sensor **directly** from Pi(B).

> DHT11 SENSOR <---> AAAAAA <---> BBBBB

#### What I have done :

I can successfully get data of the sensor from Pi(A) by using Adafruit's libraries.
(or by running python scripts with "exe" node on Node-Red)

#### The question :

So, How can i access the sensor on the GPIO of Pi(A) **Directly** from Pi(B).
I have been searching all day and all I found are about parallel computing , distributed computing ,etc.
Is it possible to create a TCP/IP tunnel between the two Pis.

Thanks in advance to you all. Cheers.

Comment: It would help if we knew more what you were actually trying to accomplish. Why not connect the sensor to the other Pi? What do you mean by access? Read the sensor data directly as if it was connected to the second PI? or just get a data value?

Comment: Sorry about my poor detailed question.

What I want to accomplish is 
to get the data of sensor **(which is attach to Pi(A) )** from **Pi(B)** through TCP/IP Connection or any form of direct communication between the two Pis. 

[link](http://imgur.com/uen0eVC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view you have two options:

1. Install node-red on both Pis. On Pi(A) - the sensor-Pi - you can do the stuff you need, f.i. read sensor values. In your special case with the DHT11, you can start with installing the npm `node-dht-sensor` (like mentioned at my 2nd point) in the node-red root folder. If you don't want to create a node for that, you can quick and dirty use the example in the readme and add this to a function node:

   ```
   var sensorLib = require('node-dht-sensor');

   // sensor connected to the GPIO 4 :
   if (sensorLib.initialize(22, 4)) {
       var readout = sensorLib.read();
       result = {
           temperature: readout.temperature.toFixed(2)
           humidity: readout.humidity.toFixed(2)
       }
       msg.payload = result;
   } else {
       msg.error = 'Failed to initialize sensor';
   }
   return msg;
   ```

   Node-red itself will then be configured to provide a http endopoint, where it accepts calls  like GET /sensor1 and replies with the measured value from the RawSerial/GPIO node. Pi(B) can be used to query this resource.
2. Just Install https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-dht-sensor on the Sensor-PI (A) and modify the example given in the readme or use my version above. You have to create a webserver around this, see the node's own http-module for that. Small example:

   ```
   var sensorLib = require('node-dht-sensor'); 

   var server = require('http').createServer(function(request, response){
       // Handle every request, get values from DHT11
       var result, readout;
       readout = sensorLib.read();
       result = {
           temperature: readout.temperature.toFixed(2)
           humidity: readout.humidity.toFixed(2)
       }

       response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
       response.end(JSON.stringify(result));
   });

   if (sensorLib.initialize(22, 4)) {
       server.listen(8080);
   } else {
       console.log("Error initializing sensor!");
   }
   ```

Disclaimer: This code is neither fault tolerant nor handling special cases. And untested.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will try out first and Post the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. My Question has been solved.

I ran a TCP Node on Pi(B) (If Node-Red is installed) Else run a "netcat" command to listen on a specific port.

On Pi(A), I wrote this "very basic error prone" script in python (to read data from my DHT11 sensor and to send that data to Pi(B) -

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import socket
import Adafruit_DHT

host = '192.168.0.28'
port = 8888

try:

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

except socket.error:
    print ' Failed to create a socket.'
    sys.exit(1);

print 'Socket Created'


sensor_args = { '11': Adafruit_DHT.DHT11,
                            '22': Adafruit_DHT.DHT22,
                            '2302': Adafruit_DHT.AM2302 }
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1] in sensor_args:
    sensor = sensor_args[sys.argv[1]]
    pin = sys.argv[2]
else:
    print 'usage: sudo ./Adafruit_DHT.py [11|22|2302] GPIOpin#'
    print 'example: sudo ./Adafruit_DHT.py 2302 4 - Read from an AM2302 con$
    sys.exit(1)


humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
        print 'Temp={0:0.1f}*C  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidit$
        s.connect((host, port))
        print 'Connected to Node-Red.'
        value1 = str(temperature)
        value2 = str(humidity)
        value3 = value1+" "+value2
        s.send(value3);
        s.close();
else:
        s.close();
        print 'Failed to Access the Sensor.Run the script again.'
```

---

For those who are using DHT11/DHT22. This is the link for Adafruit's DHT Codes on Github :
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT

(If there is other way around , please tell me. I am willing to learn all the alternatives.)
Cheers.